# Как удалить атрибут через Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Вот код.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cabinet/registration" style="font-size: 16px;">

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" name="registration" class="registration_submit" id="registration" disabled />
    </form>
```

Jquery

```
function checkParams() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var re_password = $('#re_password').val();

    if(email.length != 0 && password.length != 0 && re_password.length != 0) {

        $("#reg").prop("disabled", true);  
    } else {
        $("#reg").prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

Почему не удаляется атрибут disabled у кнопки?

Comment: @duddeniska, а зачем вы используете обработчики событий внутри тегов? Кто вас такой бяке научил? И за счет IE уже не отмажитесь )) Check-up особенно порадовал, но это уже мелочи ))

Answer (score 1):

[[@duddeniska](/users/3435/duddeniska)](/users/3435/duddeniska), давайте, я попробую предложить вам [немного другой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/j6hrheep/), а вы подумаете и потом сами решите - брать на вооружение или нет.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="password" name="re_password" />
    <input type="submit" id="reg" value="Регистрация" />
</form>
```

JS можете расположить в любом удобном вам месте:

```
$(function(){
    var checkFilds = $(':text, :password'),
        sbmt = $('#reg').prop('disabled', true);
    checkFilds.on('input', function(){
        var empty = checkFilds.filter(function(){
            var cVal = $.trim($(this).val());
            return cVal == '' || cVal.length < 3;
        }).length;
        sbmt.prop('disabled', empty);
    });
});
```

Мы не будем пропускать, если есть хоть одно пустое поле или поле в котором меньше трёх символов. Все остальные усовершенствования и доработки - это я оставляю вам ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#reg")` - это что за элемент? В вашем отрывке коде `id=reg`  я не вижу.

И еще по коду событие onkeyup - не совсем подходящее, на мой взгляд. Пользователи имееют привычку вставлять, копировать логины, мылы.